# google maps XML Import

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

hi I am trying to develop an application where I import an XML file with addresses and then google maps should tell me the closest places according to my current location.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: I have a list of addresses. The User enters his current location.On the Basis of the location user entered, we have display the distances of places in the order of increasing distance.(closest one first)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [**`google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween()`**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#spherical) to calculate the distance between 2 LatLng's. When you didn't know the LatLng's  first request them via the [geocoding-service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#Geocoder).

This will give you the calculated distance between the points.

When you wan't to get the distance based on a route(e.g. driving-distance) request the [directions-Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#DirectionsService) , the response will contain route and the distance. To request distances for multiple routes with 1 request you also may use a [DistanceMatrixRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#DistanceMatrixRequest)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the perfect use case for [Distance Matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix). You'll have to parse the XML file first, and then create a distance matrix request that includes all your locations. That will return a response that gives you the distances to all locations.